# How to deploy a nextjs Server side application on cpanel using Application Manager?

Tags: node.js, next.js, cpanel

I'm seeking assistance with setting up a server-side Next.js application. Node.js is already installed on my cPanel, but I'm unsure how to create a Node.js application. I reached out to my hosting provider, and they suggested using the Application Manager.

I've attempted to use the Application Manager but lack experience in navigating it effectively. If anyone has insights or guidance on deploying a server-side Next.js application on cPanel through the Application Manager, I would greatly appreciate your help.

Thank you in advance for your response.